# What were all of those other chambers and floating bat bodies in the spaceship in Lifeforce (1985)?

Tags: plot-device, lifeforce

In [*Lifeforce*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeforce_(film)) (1985), the crew of a joint British and American space mission to explore approaching [Haley’s Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_Comet) discover an alien spaceship in the tail (coma) of Haley’s Comet that seems to contain three humanoid creatures in crystal-like chambers. Most notably, “[Space Girl](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Girl).”

The rest of the film follows what happens when these three humanoid aliens are recovered from the alien ship and brought aboard the British and American space shuttle “Churchill” — and eventually come back to Earth itself — but what about the other chambers pictured on the ship? Ditto with the floating bat bodies in the chamber; are they dead creatures or are they just in hibernation or something. Images attached.

Are they simply all empty or contain the bodies of dead space creatures?

Is the spaceship ultimately a hive of “space vampires” that recycles its population every 75-79 years as it approaches Earth again with Haley’s Comet?

At the end of the film, one sees the “alpha” space creature (“[Space Girl](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Girl)”) transmitting lifeforce power to the alien spaceship that is in geosynchronous orbit over London (U.K.) where most of the film’s action takes place. So is she transmitting lifeforce power to the ship to revive the seemingly “dead” bat-like creatures in orbit?

[image: Upon entering the alien ship, the astronauts see a bunch of floating bat bodies. Always a good sign that means, “Welcome! Make yourself at home.” I guess.]

[image: The scene at the beginning of Lifeforce where seemingly rational astronauts discover nude humanoids in space and decide it is a good idea to “rescue” them because there its a hot nude lady there.]

---

***NOTE**: Looking for some kind of canonical answer from either the film itself or source book “[The Space Vampires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Vampires)” (1976) by Colin Wilson from which the script for *Lifeforce* was based on. Apparently the script for the movie was rushed as well as altered from the source material (which often happens) so perhaps some details went missing in the process. From a budget standpoint it would make sense to just darken the other chambers while filming and not imply each one was filled with anything, but the imagery in the film leaves many questions as to what exactly was up with all of those other chambers in the alien ship.*